# C - Could runtime code change between executions?

Tags: c, security, runtime, function-pointers

I'm learning about software anti-tampering and I wanted to start making some experiments. This is one of them.

Leaving aside the undefined behavior, I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test();

int main() {
    // Code doing all kind of things like calling functions,
    // accessing global variables, calling things from .so's, etc...

    for (int i = 0; i < ((char *)test) - ((char *)main); ++i) {
        printf("%c", ((char *)main)[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void test() {
}
```

I have made some experimets and it always prints the same string in my mac:

```
����H)�HcM�H9��.H�=kH�����HcM����5�E�E���E�����H�=@��1ɉE��H��]�`
```

Could runtime code change between executions?

Note that I'm asking about runtime code in RAM, not image code that resides in the program file.

What I suspect is that between executions the loader may make the runtime code different depending on the process memory location or something like that.

Comment: Are you invoking undefined behavior? If so, then sure. If not, then no.

Comment: Usually, the text segment (the code) of the program is in a read-only segment of memory and therefore cannot change while a program is running.  Dynamically loaded code (shared libraries, DLLs) are slightly different, but usually end up in write-protected (read-only) memory too.  Some o/s (embedded ones in particular) may not have that much memory protection; the rules would be different.  Assuming you're running a modern Mac (Mac OS X or macOS), then your code is safely in read-only memory.  Note that the relative layout of `main()` and `test()` is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler. My question is about the code changing between many process executions of the same program, i.e., calling ./a.out many times. Would the runtime code always be the same?

Comment: Mostly, but address space layout randomization (ASLR) might affect the positions of some of the shared libraries etc.  However, within the code that corresponded to a single object file, the relative addresses would be the same, AFAIK,

Answer (score 0):

The executable instructions of a program are stored in the code segment portion of the object file.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment):

> When the loader places a program into memory so that it may be executed, various memory regions are allocated (in particular, as pages), corresponding to both the segments in the object files and to segments only needed at run time. **The code segment of an object file is loaded into a corresponding code segment in memory.**
>
> The code segment in memory is typically **read-only** and has a fixed size, so on embedded systems it can usually be **placed in read-only memory (ROM)**...
>
> If the code segment is **not read-only**, then the particular architecture allows **self-modifying code**.

So unless your program consists of [self-modifying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) which some languages like PERL or Python permit, you do not have fear different code being executed every time the program is run.

Answer (score 0):

`(char *)test` This invokes undefined behavior, you cannot cast from a function pointer to an object pointer. Same with the cast from `main`. Anything can happen, including program crashes or any form of behavior.

Pointer arithmetic between two pointers that do not point to the same array also invokes undefined behavior. So the outcome of this program is completely unpredictable.

You need to use `uintptr_t` instead of `char*` - still no guarantee that it can hold the address, but at least there will be no bugs. And you have to do the subtraction on `uintptr_t`, not on pointer types.

Accessing the code section of a program as if it was data, might raise hardware exceptions on some systems.

Apart from the above, there is no reason why the binary would change between executions if you didn't change the code. There is [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on many OS, so the absolute addresses may however change.